# Android. When extends TextView property singleLine as true breaks canvas drawing

Tags: android, canvas, textview, drawing

My class extends TextView class.

I try draw path in onDraw method with code

```
 @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        TextPaint paint = this.getPaint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

        RectF rectF = new RectF(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        Path path = new Path();
        path.addArc(rectF, -180, 180);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```

But then i property of TextView singleLine as true draw nothing, but if it's false - all fine works. And draw arc, why?

Comment: translate your `canvas` by horizontal scroll offset

Comment: Just curious, but why are you extending `TextView` if you're not drawing the text? That is, you're not calling `super.onDraw(canvas);`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
android:maxLines="1"
```

instead of single line call